# SQL Server - Fill date range gaps

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have records of employee employment that contain date ranges. There are some gaps between employments. I need to fill the gaps with date ranges and set them to inactive. All employees are to be parsed.

```
| ID | START_DATE | END_DATE   |Active
|----|------------|------------|--------
| 2  | 01/01/2019 | 30/09/2019 |   1     <--- gap after this
| 2  | 01/11/2019 | 01/12/2020 |   1
| 2  | 02/12/2019 | (null)     |   1

| ID | START_DATE | END_DATE   |Active
|----|------------|------------|--------
| 2  | 01/01/2019 | 30/09/2019 |   1
| 2  | 01/10/2019 | 31/10/2019 |   0     <---- insert new record
| 2  | 01/11/2019 | 01/12/2020 |   1
| 2  | 02/12/2019 | (null)     |   1
```

Is that even possible? I'm thinking about group by Id and order by startdate but that's all that comes to my mind. I'm not that good in SQL. I've tried to google but didn't find what I was looking for.
Thanks in advance for any links or suggestions.

Comment: A calendar table would make this quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this too (i'm borrowing Aaron's table data):

```sql
select gaps.*
  from (
  select *, lead(start_date) over(partition by ID order by start_date) as next_date
  from Employment l
  ) s
cross apply (
    select s.id, start_date, end_date, active
    union all
  select id, dateadd(day, 1, end_date), dateadd(day, -1, next_date), 0 as active
  where datediff(day, s.end_date, s.next_date) > 1
  ) gaps
```

What this does is to get next period's startdate (LEAD call), and if it's after 1 day since current enddate, we create another period with the gap dates